# Powershell passing multiple parameters from one script to another

Tags: powershell

I have a simple Powershell script which accepts 2 parameters (*script1.ps1*):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][object] $parameter1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][object] $parameter2
)

Write-Output "executing script...."
```

From a different script, I load the parameters and call the script above:

```
$parameters = @{
    parameter1 = $parameter1
    parameter2 = $parameter2
}

# execute script with parameters
& "./script1.ps1" $parameters
```

When I run this script which calls *script1.ps1* in Debug mode, I always get prompted for *parameter2*, even though *parameter2* contains a value.  If I then supply a value at the prompt and then hit the breakpoint in *script1.ps1*, I can hover over *$parameter1*, and it contains a collection of both parameters.

How do I do this correctly so that the parameters show up in *script1.ps1* in the correct position?

Comment: To pass a set of parameter through a hashtable, you need to do splatting. Change the `$` for a `@`  ... `& "./script1.ps1" @parameters`  [About_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Change `$parameters` for `@parameters` thats how splatting works

Comment: You could use a directory to store the variables. It would make it easier to call them in either script.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks very much for the quick response, now works as expected.

Comment: @SagePourpre thanks to you as well.  I'd not heard of splatting prior and will definitely use more in the future.